# Как выполнить глубокое копирование Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Есть класс Patient со свойствами:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Symptoms *symptoms;
@property (assign, nonatomic) Status status;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <PatientDelegate> delegate;
```

Есть класс Symptoms со свойствами:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat temperature;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL headache;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL stomach_ache;
```

Оба класса реализуют протокол NSCopying:

```
- (nonnull id)copyWithZone:(nullable NSZone *)zone {
    Patient *newPatient = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    [newPatient setName:self.name];
    [newPatient setSymptoms:self.symptoms];
    [newPatient setStatus:self.status];
    [newPatient setDelegate:self.delegate];
    return newPatient;
 }

- (nonnull id)copyWithZone:(nullable NSZone *)zone {
    Symptoms *newSymptoms = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    [newSymptoms setTemperature:self.temperature];
    [newSymptoms setHeadache:self.headache];
    [newSymptoms setStomach_ache:self.stomach_ache];
    return newSymptoms;
}
```

Также есть класс Doctor:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *history;

- (void)makeNoteIn:(Patient *)patient card:(NSMutableArray *)history;
- (void)report;
```

Когда пациента пролечили, у доктора вызывается метод makeNoteIn:

```
- (void)makeNoteIn:(Patient *)patient card:(NSMutableArray *)history {
    Patient *newRecord = [patient copy];

    [history addObject:newRecord];
}
```

После того, как сделана запись, у пациента все property возвращаются в исходные значения. Пока мы находимся в методе makeNoteIn, то в history лежат ссылки на объекты, у которых ещё не "обжуленные" значения. Как только из метода выходим, происходит сброс на исходное значение у каждого объекта. 
[image: Описание классов Patient и Symptoms]

[image: Корректные значения свойств у объектов в history]

[image: Сброшенные значения после выхода из метода makeNoteIn]

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем history нужен доктору, если вы в него ничего не записываете. Если записываете, но в другом месте, и к проблеме это не относится - пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос. Представьте себя на месте человека, в первый раз видящего этот код – разобраться здесь крайне трудно, уменьшите пример до минимального и разъясните лучше, в чём проблема.

Comment: Доктор хранит историю с пациентами, с чем они приходили. Как только статус пациента изменился на Good, то вызывается метод у доктора: [self makeNoteIn:patient card:self.history];

Comment: Вот эту строку `[newPatient setSymptoms:self.symptoms];` - стоит заменить на `[newPatient setSymptoms:[self.symptoms copy]];` – тогда копирования будут работать верно. Если это не решает проблему – дело не в копировании, задавайте новый вопрос или редактируйте существующий, слишком много здесь лишней информации, [не относящейся к проблеме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.